# iPhone UIView frame animation inconsistent why?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I have an app that uses an image loaded in from an UIImagePickerController instance. Once the picker is dismissed so as to reduce the jarring transition from the picker layout to the layout of the next function I initially have the UIImageView for the image fill the whole screen and then when the picker is dismissed the image 'squeezes' up to the top left of the screen.

from the initWithFrame...

```
targetPicView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
[targetPicView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

this in a function called after dismissing the picker...

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"squeeze" context:context];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[targetPicView setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 130.0, 150.0)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The weird thing is that this works great when the image has been chosen from the library, the view shrinks down with the top left corner in place just as I planned but... *If the image comes from the camera then the view shrinks with the top right corner in place instead* and appears to come in from the left side of the screen.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Hmm I guess nobody knows. I shall try and work it out myself then once I finish this sprint and add this as a bug to fix in the next one.

Comment: Just a comment, it may be that the new view does not have a top status bar (where the battery info etc is) defined (at least that was my problem). Once I manually set my new frame equal to my replacing one it worked.